# Add id "active" to image in revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I use revolution slider and I would like to add an ID call "active-img" to the image in the slide active (with class ="active-revslide").
The code is like that :

```
<li data-index="rs-231" class="tp-revslider-slidesli active-revslide">
<div class="slotholder" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg "style="background-color:undefined;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(http://xxxx.com);background-size:cover;background-position:center top;width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://xxxx.com"></div></div>
```

and I want that :

```
<li data-index="rs-231" class="tp-revslider-slidesli active-revslide">
<div class="slotholder" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:0;width:100%;height:100%;">
<div class="tp-bgimg defaultimg "style="background-color:undefined;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(http://xxxx.com);background-size:cover;background-position:center top;width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://xxxx.com" id="active-img"></div></div>
```

How to do that? Is it possible?